# How to convert a radius value to a percentage refering to the parent box?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, percentages

I know the width and height of the outer box. I also know the radius of the large circle inside. All values are in absolute values. My question is how to convert the value of the radius to a percentage refering to the size of the outer box? So, if the outer box resizes, the radius of the circle adjusts accordingly.

[image: 1]

I suspect that I must do some kind of ratio between width and height of the outer box but I do not know how. Thank you.

**EDIT**
sorry, yes the (x,y) of the center of the circle are know.

Comment: There should also be the coordinates of the center of the disc given, or should we find them somehow?

Comment: it is given. Sorry.